# element_children vs elements in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Is there difference between the `element_children` and `elements` methods in `Nokogiri`?

There is no document about `elements` and as far as I know both methods work same way.
http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-element_children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are the same. [`elements` is an alias of `element_children`](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/v1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb#L451). `element_children` is defined as a [C function in `xml_node.c`](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/v1.6.3.1/ext/nokogiri/xml_node.c#L643-L669).

Answer (score 2):

[On this link](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet) you can see a detailed description:

> node.elements # alias: node.element_children # Get the list of child
>   Elements of this node as a NodeSet.

So yes, they are the same.